# spring can not send css & js resources

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I use spring mvc and spring security for web app and tomcat as web application. I use mvc:resources to handle resources requests. But chrome console display following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/web-resources/jquery.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
:8080/favicon.ico  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

This picture is my project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

My web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <!-- security config-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

And my spring-mvc-servlet.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="java"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/web-resources/**" location="/web-resources" cache-period="31556926"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/favicon.ico" location="/web-resources" cache-period="31556926"/>
</beans>
```

And security.xml is:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/web-resources**" access="permitAll"/>
        <form-login
                login-page="/login"
                default-target-url="/user/index"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="abcd" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

The following is view jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>

<html>
<body>
<h1 id="banner">Login to Security Demo</h1>
<form name="f" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>"
      method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='j_username'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='j_password'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit">&nbsp;<input name="reset" type="reset"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="web-resources/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your mvc resource mapping seems not set correct.

Try to change

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/web-resources/**" location="/web-resources" cache-period="31556926"/>
```

to

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/web-resources/**" location="/web-resources/" cache-period="31556926"/>
```

and also add following code to your spring security xml:

```
<http pattern="/web-resources/**" security="none"/>
```